# How to bind using the ng-model in angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I just started using angular js and I was playing with the ng-model directive but I can't figure out what im doing wrong. I want the input email value to show in the h1 tag as I'm typing. pretty much I'm not getting anything show in the h1 tag as I type.

```
<body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-pane>
        <ion-content style="margin-top: 163px">
            <div ng-controller="loginController">
                <form action="">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col col-50 col-offset-25">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="item item-text-wrap">
                                    <div class="list">
                                        <label class="item item-input">
                                            <i class="icon ion-email placeholder       icon"></i><input type="email" placeholder="Email" ng-model="email" />
                                            <h1>{{email}}</h1>
                                        </label>
                                  <label class="item item-input">
                                      <i class="icon ion-locked placeholder-icon"></i><input type="text" placeholder="Password" />
                                  </label>
                                  <br/>
                                  <button class="button button-full button-positive">Clock Me In</button>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </form>
      </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-pane>
</body>
```

this is my javascript

```
var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

app.controller('loginController', function($scope)
{

})
```

Comment: you need to pass the value from controller like $scope.email = "anyemailadddress@gmail.com" then it show in in your page.

Comment: Note that if you assigned `type="email"`, the result will only be displayed when the field is valid

Comment: lol that was the problem the type email. i changed my code to type text and it worked. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your changes are not displayed on screen because while you are typing the email it is invalid. Invalid values are reflected to `$scope` as `null`, so there is nothing to show.

As suggested in comments, you can change it `type="text"`. Since you removed validation, you'll see the text on both screen and in your `$scope`, however you'll sacrifice validation.

If you still want to use email validation, and want to see it in screen/`$scope` you can use `ng-model-options` as described [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions).

Using `ng-model-options` you can allow invalid values to be stored in your `$scope`.

Try adding `ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}"` to your `type="email"` input.